# Property of symmetric tridiagonal matrices with an eigenvalue of multiplicity $m$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices, tridiagonal-matrices

> Show that if $T$ is a symmetric tridiagonal matrix and an eigenvalue has multiplicity $k$, then at least $k−1$ subdiagonal elements of $T$ are zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint.* If $T$ has $r$ zeros on its sub/super-diagonal, we can split $T$ into a direct sum of $r+1$ diagonal blocks, each with *entrywise nonzero* sub/super-diagonal. So, it suffices to show that every such diagonal sub-block has a spectrum of distinct eigenvalues.